# Different behavior depending on log4j config file location

Tags: java, log4j

I have **log4j.xml** config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">
<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/"
    debug="true">
    <appender name="console" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
        <param name="target" value="System.out" />
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="[%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS}] %-5p [%c] %m%n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>
    <logger name="org.apache.commons.httpclient">
        <level value="fatal" />
    </logger>

    <logger name="org.apache.http.client">
        <level value="fatal" />
    </logger>
    <logger name="org.apache.http.wire">
        <level value="fatal" />
    </logger>

    <logger name="org.apache.http.headers">
        <level value="fatal" />
    </logger>
    <logger name="org.apache.http.impl">
        <level value="fatal" />
    </logger>
    <root>
        <level value="DEBUG" />
        <appender-ref ref="console" />
    </root>
</log4j:configuration>
```

If it's in main package, and project started like this:

```
java -jar -Dlog4j.configuration=log4j.xml api.jar
```

It works as I expected (don't see `org.apache.http` logs).

But if I place it in **/resources/log4j.xml**, and project started like this:

```
java -jar -Dlog4j.configuration=/resources/log4j.xml api.jar
```

All rules for ignoring `org.apache.http` logs doesn't work, and I see all this logs:

```
[15:09:24,127] DEBUG [org.apache.http.headers] http-outgoing-0 << HTTP/1.1 202 Accepted
[15:09:24,127] DEBUG [org.apache.http.headers] http-outgoing-0 << Content-Type: text/json
[15:09:24,127] DEBUG [org.apache.http.headers] http-outgoing-0 << Date: Fri, 25 Dec 2015 21:09:24 GMT
[15:09:24,127] DEBUG [org.apache.http.headers] http-outgoing-0 << DD-POOL: propjoe
[15:09:24,127] DEBUG [org.apache.http.headers] http-outgoing-0 << Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=15724800;
[15:09:24,127] DEBUG [org.apache.http.headers] http-outgoing-0 << X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
[15:09:24,127] DEBUG [org.apache.http.headers] http-outgoing-0 << Content-Length: 16
[15:09:24,127] DEBUG [org.apache.http.headers] http-outgoing-0 << Connection: keep-alive
```

Why?

Answer (score 0):

When adding a "log4j.debug=true" to the environment you can watch the initialization of log4j on the command line. So you can see which config file is searched in which location, and which one will be picked up for being used as configuration. I assume your file in the resource folder is not found, but something else.

Remove the leading slash. The log4j.xml is loaded as resource and must be found in classpath.

Comment: No, I see that log4j file was found. But it ignores all `logger` params =/

Comment: And you are sure that the config file in resources is exactly the same as in your package root?